# Tweepy add_list_members() Fails Without Error

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

I am having trouble with Tweepy while trying to add multiple users to a list.

I think this should work (members_to_add is a list of ids):

```
api.add_list_members(user_id = members_to_add, slug = 'testlist', owner_screen_name = 'myusername', list_id = full_list_detail.id)
```

If I try the singular version instead:

```
api.add_list_member(user_id = single_member, slug = 'testlist', owner_screen_name = 'myusername', list_id = full_list_detail.id)
```

...then I can add members just fine. But this eventually runs into the rate limiting and errors, hence my wanting to use the batch version.

The second part of the problem is that if my account is currently being blocked from adding members do to the rate limiting, the singular add_list_member will tell me so, but add_list_members doesn't seem to do that. **So I'm not sure if the call is working and suppressing the error or if it's actually not working.**

I think I have all the syntax right based on:

1. https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py
2. https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=https://qiita.com/kgtkr/items/9a97759d0e5a4aa36f6b&prev=search
3. https://kite.com/python/docs/tweepy.API.add_list_members

Any ideas on why these two extremely similar functions has mismatched returns?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

api.add_list_members(slug='testlist', screen_name='user.screen_name', owner_screen_name='@your_screen_name')